# creating sticky key mappings in vim

Tags: vim, keymapping

I have this in my vimrc file

```
nnoremap <leader>k <C-u>
```

I want to be able to continue to hold down the leader key, and just tap 'k' to scroll the screen as I like.
But, at the moment, I have to release both keys first, and then press them again to get the desired action.

How do I implement it, so that I don't have to keep releasing the leader key to get the functionality to work?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TinyMode](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2223) is a plugin that pretty much achieves what you're looking for. You could set it up so that you press `<leader>k` and then just tap `k`.

Comment: Can you explain this

nmap          <C-W>+     <C-W>+<SID>ws
    nmap          <C-W>-     <C-W>-<SID>ws
    nn <script>   <SID>ws+   <C-W>+<SID>ws
    nn <script>   <SID>ws-   <C-W>-<SID>ws
    nmap          <SID>ws    <Nop>

These mappings make the builtin CTRL-W_+ and CTRL-W_- (in short ^W+, ^W-)
keys a little smarter: You can now type ^W++- instead of ^W+^W+^W- to change
the window size.  It's like ^W+ enters a "Vim mode" with the new keys + and - . 

I cant get it  working. Seems to be what I need though

Comment: I believe that's the example used for what you would need to do if you don't install TinyMode. The point is it's complicated. If you install the TinyMode plugin you should be able to put a few function calls in your vimrc to achieve both window resizing and what you're looking for. The plugin is very well documented; have a read of the doc file and look at the examples and I'll be happy to answer any questions you have.

Comment: Thanks for the help, only got round to trying it; does what I need.