# How can I make this mapping work repetitively?

Tags: vim, mapping

I just created this mapping `nmap <Leader><right> :bnext<CR>`, I am using vim remotely via `putty` so `<CTRL-TAB>` is not available.
I would like being able to press `<Leader>` and then `<right>` several times and the buffer will move sereral times.
But at the moment I have to press both keys then release then press again

Can this be done ?

Comment: Tip: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Comment: Same question at [creating sticky key mappings in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7267629).

Comment: Plugins for this are [tinymode.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2223), [submode](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2467), [tinykeymap](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4199).

Comment: As an alternative solution why not use some of the function keys as they are normally left unused. `nnoremap <f4> :bnext<cr>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim doesn't support *chording*; i.e. you can only combine (mostly alphabetic) keys with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and/or <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier keys. `<Leader><right>` means pressing and then releasing the (by default) <kbd>\</kbd> key, then pressing and releasing the <kbd>→</kbd> cursor key.

If you want a mapping that you can quickly repeat with a single keypress, you have to choose a single key (combination), e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>:

```
:nnoremap <C-n> :bnext<CR>
```

That said, there are attempts to implement *chording* via plugins; you could try the [arpeggio - Key mappings for simultaneously pressed keys](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2425) plugin.

Comment: Yes but as I said I use `putty` so `<CTRL-whatever>` is not poassible

Comment: Huh? Even PuTTY supports the default `<C-[a-z]>` sequences (unless misconfigured). And you can use the (at least unmodified) function keys `<F1>` .. `<F12>`.